# How to create a multiple hyperlink in in single php line

Tags: php, html

I have tried below code; as you can see in bold line i want to add two hyperlink but i am not getting results.I want to create a variable hyperlink.

```
<?php
echo "<!DOCTYPE html>";
echo "<html>";
echo "<title> disorders </title>";
echo "<body>";
include ('menu.php');
echo "<br>";
echo "<br>";
$disorder = $_GET ['disorder'];
$sql_disorder= "SELECT * FROM `disorders raw datasets` WHERE `Name of disorder` =  '$disorder'  ";
if ($result_disorder = mysqli_query($conn, $sql_disorder));
{   
        echo "<table border='1' cellpadding='2' cellspacing='1'>  ";
           echo "<tr>";
                echo "<th>Accession ID</th>";
                echo "<th>Title</th>";
                echo "<th>Abstract</th>";
                echo "<th>Tissue type</th>";
                echo "<th>PMID</th>";
                echo "<th>Other information</th>";
           echo "</tr>";
        while($row_disorder = mysqli_fetch_array($result_disorder))
        {
            echo "<tr>";
                **echo "<td><a href='https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/query/acc.cgi?acc=  href='https://www.ebi.ac.uk/arrayexpress/experiments/" . $row_disorder['Accession ID'] . "  '  ' >"   . $row_disorder['Accession ID'] . "</a> </td>";**
                echo "<td>" . $row_disorder['Title'] .   " </td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row_disorder['Abstract'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row_disorder['Tissue type'] .   " </td>";
                echo "<td><a href='https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/" . $row_disorder['PMID'] . " '>"  . $row_disorder['PMID']  . "</a></td>";
                echo "<td><a href='disorder_info.php?" . $row_disorder['Other information'] . " ' >" . $row_disorder['Other information']  . "</a></td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
    }
echo "</body>";
echo "</html>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you are using two href in a single tag, that does not support by any dom. Although replace your code with the following line.

```html
echo "
<td><a href='https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/query/acc.cgi?acc=' href='https://www.ebi.ac.uk/arrayexpress/experiments/' " . $row_disorder['Accession ID'] . " '  '>"   . $row_disorder['Accession ID'] . "</a> </td>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use [urlencode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) for it to work

```
$queryString = urlencode("href='https://www.ebi.ac.uk/arrayexpress/experiments/{$row_disorder['Accession ID']}'");

echo "
<td>
    <a href='https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/query/acc.cgi?acc=$queryString'>
       {$row_disorder['Accession ID']}
    </a>
</td>";
```

Comment: I tested and it's working for me. What's the issue you're facing?